# Can't add objects to a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So I have the following code:

```
NSMutableArray *array
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject: object1];
[array addObject: object2];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

When I use the app in my iPod connected to my Mac, NSLog writes just null, I don't get object1 object2. What am I doing wrong?

PS: array is a property in .h `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;`

Comment: Can you post an `NSLog` of the two objects as well?

Comment: Do you `@synthesize array;` in the .m file?

Comment: Also if you already have this as a property, what's the point of doing  `NSMutableArray *array` (in which btw you're missing a semicolon) ?

Comment: @Stefan it wouldn't build without `@synthesize` or getter/setter methods.

Comment: @Adam, I know, I just want to find out if the OP actually uses `@synthesize` or does their own implementation of getter/setter.

Answer (score 2):

Should it be:

```
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `[[NSMutableArray array] init]` should be `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`. That would work but its not a proper way to initialize objects. You didn't post what your `array` is, i assume you declared it wrong. It should be a pointer to a `NSMutableArray` object. Here is a working code:

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject: @"a"];
[array addObject: @"b"];
NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Comment: He may have listed it as a member.

Comment: @adr If you have a synthesized property you don't need a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your array at all, that's why it doesn't return anything.

```
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject: object1];
[array addObject: object2];
NSLog(@" Array is:%@",array);
```

Remember to release it afterwards(unless you are using ARC)

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it in one line.

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil];
 NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Comment: `arrayWithObjects` is a class method

Comment: @Alladinian right, he should have used `initWithObjects:` instead.

Comment: @Adam Or `[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil]`

Answer (score 0):

You declared array as a property. Its corresponding iVar gets initialized to nil. 
So in your init method you have to initialize it:

Assuming you used

```
@synthesize array;
```

In your init method

```
if (self) {
//other init stuff
array = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
}
```

Then when adding stuff

```
[self.array addObject: object];
```

Also note that he objects you put in there have to be properly initialized and r not nil.
So try to log this too

```
NSLog("the object %@ was put in array. Array contains: %@",object, self.array);
```

And in dealloc, release your array!