# add convert UTF8 string to array

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, hebrew

i converting Hebrew string and trying yo add it to array , this is the code:

```
 NSMutableArray * myarray;

    // @property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *stringArray;
    for (NSString * item in stringArray) {

        NSData * UTF8 = [item dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSString * myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:UTF8 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"myString = %@",myString); // Hebrew str log fine

        [myarray addObject:myString];

    }

    NSString * ConvetData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myarray];

    NSLog(@"ConvetData = %@",ConvetData); // null

    newitem.ingredient = ConvetData;
```

the array coms out as null , how can i crate one string from my convert data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't add objects to a NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861600/cant-add-objects-to-a-nsmutablearray)

Comment: FYI - it's a really bad idea to convert an `NSArray` to an `NSString` the way you are doing it other than for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `myarray`: `NSMutableArray *myarray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`